# How to remove columns having NULL values?

Tags: sql

How can I remove `NULL` cells in my query because some records appears even if the `CompanyName` doesnt exist?

```
SELECT ClientID, CompanyName, FirstName, LastName, Street, City
  FROM Client
  WHERE CompanyName LIKE '%G%' Or FirstName LIKE '%J%' OR LastName LIKE '%J%'
  OR Street LIKE '%J%' OR City LIKE '%J%' Or ContactNo LIKE '%0%'
  AND ClientTypeID = 2
```

Comment: Do you want to exclude all rows where `CompanyName` is null?

Comment: YES! Because some records do not have a CompanyName

Answer (score 6):

To exclude all rows where CompanyName is null, you need to add

```
AND CompanyName is NOT NULL
```

you might need parentheses after your `WHERE` and after your last `OR` condition

Comment: Thank You Very Much! :) I use this command on my Client Search TextBox

Comment: +1 for the reminder that there should be parenthesis. AND precedes OR, so they definitely should be surrounded with parenthesis (if not just for the ease of reading).

Answer (score 1):

Naively, just use

```
SELECT ClientID, CompanyName, FirstName, LastName, Street, City
FROM Client
WHERE CompanyName is not NULL and (CompanyName LIKE '%G%' Or FirstName LIKE '%J%' Or LastName LIKE '%J%' Or Street LIKE '%J%' Or City LIKE '%J%' Or ContactNo LIKE '%0%'
AND ClientTypeID = 2)
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much! :) I use this command on my Client Search TextBox

Answer (score 0):

`CompanyName like '%G'`

will fail if `CompanyName` is `null`, won't it?

If your DB doesn't behave that way, just add

`AND CompanyName IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Thank You Very Much! :) I use this command on my Client Search TextBox

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ClientID, CompanyName, FirstName, LastName, Street, City
FROM Client
WHERE (CompanyName LIKE '%G%' Or FirstName LIKE '%J%' Or LastName LIKE '%J%' Or Street LIKE '%J%' Or City LIKE '%J%' Or ContactNo LIKE '%0%' AND ClientTypeID = 2) AND CompanyName IS NOT NULL;
```

The problem is that you have or statements. Even if CompanyName doesn't fit row LastName might fit. Since you use or's in your filter result will be then included.

And you are mixing or's, and's both without any parenthesis. You shouldn't do that. You should eighter write:

```
SELECT ClientID, CompanyName, FirstName, LastName, Street, City
FROM Client
WHERE (CompanyName LIKE '%G%' Or FirstName LIKE '%J%' Or LastName LIKE '%J%' Or Street LIKE '%J%' Or City LIKE '%J%' Or ContactNo LIKE '%0%') AND ClientTypeID = 2;
```

or

```
SELECT ClientID, CompanyName, FirstName, LastName, Street, City
FROM Client
WHERE CompanyName LIKE '%G%' Or FirstName LIKE '%J%' Or LastName LIKE '%J%' Or Street LIKE '%J%' Or City LIKE '%J%' Or (ContactNo LIKE '%0%' AND ClientTypeID = 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

remove all nulls from all columns

```
declare @ex as nvarchar(max) = ''
declare @_null as nvarchar(max)
set @_null = ''

select @_null += 'isnull(' + QUOTENAME(column_name) + ',0) as ' + QUOTENAME(column_name) + ','

from sample.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where TABLE_NAME = 'table';

set @_null = left(@_null,len(@_null) - 1);

set @ex = 'select ' + @_null + ' from table';

exec sp_executesql @ex;
```